# Setting up hanging indent in paragraph

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have found in the documentation references to first line indent or end indent for a paragraph. But how do I set a hanging indent using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Related [How to set a certain number of spaces or indents before a Paragraph in Google Docs using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55641163/1595451), [Indent Paragraph with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63953619/1595451)

Comment: Thank you for the related addition. It seems that adding space for paragraph is straight forward but a hanging indent seems to be more challenging.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I cannot find where the special indent is documented in google app script. I truly do not know if the exposed the API for special indents.

Comment: Add more details about what you read on the documentation references and a code example of how you tried to use the first line indent and the start indent.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a Hanging Indent in a Google Document by Google App Script. It is important to note that the process to identify these methods can be easily established by trial-and-error testing.

The method for a Hanging Indent is `setIndentStart(indentStart)` [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setindentstartindentstart)

- `getParaDetails()` uses a same document to show some indent settings.

  - Paragraph#1: Index Start = 56.69291338582678 (Hanging Indent)
  - Paragraph#3: Index First Line = 56.69291338582678 (First Line Indent)
- `setParaDetails()` creates a hanging indent and a first line indent.

---

```
function getParaDetails() {

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paras = body.getParagraphs();
  Logger.log(paras)
  
  for (var i=0;i<paras.length;i++){
  Logger.log("i="+i+", Index Start = "+paras[i].getIndentStart()+", Index First Line = "+paras[i].getIndentFirstLine());
  }
  return;

}

function setParaDetails() {
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  
  // create indent values
  // Hanging Indent = "Index Start"
  var indentStart = 200;
  // First line indent = "indentFirstLine"
  var indentFirstLine = 100;

  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paras = body.getParagraphs();
  Logger.log(paras); //DEBUG
  
  
  // create a hanging indent on paragraph six
  paras[4].setIndentStart(indentStart);

  // create a first line indent on paragraph ten
  paras[6].setIndentFirstLine(indentFirstLine);
  
}
```

---

**Sample document - Manual indents**

[image: Sample Before]

[image: Hanging Indent]

[image: FirstLineIndent]

---

**Sample Document - Indents added by Script**

[image: Sample After]

---